# Pentaho mondrian schema workbench on Macbook pro m1?

Tags: pentaho, mondrian

Does anyone know if it is possible to install pentane mondrian schema workbench on MacBook Pro m1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can install it from here:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Pentaho-9.2/client-tools/

I opened the Foodmart schema from here:  https://github.com/pentaho/mondrian/blob/master/demo/FoodMart.xml

Works fine:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I downloaded pow-ce, but when I click on "application file", it happens nothing.